# How to create a resizable horizontal navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, resize

Question: What's the best way to create a horizontal menu with drop down capabilities that can be dynamically resized? (Or preferably, how can I edit my current menu to behave like that?)

Explanation: I'm using a thin, horizontal drop-down menu as the main navigation on my site. When the browser window is at full width, there are no problems, but when it is resized, the right-most link pushes down to the next line, as it is floated.

Horizontal menus are such a common thing, I know there have to be some common tricks and ways to create them so that they can be dynamically resized. So if trying to fix my current menu is too burdensome, I would be fine just to hear some tips or read some stuff on how to create better horizontal menus.

Here is what I think would be the main problem:

```
.menu2 li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1000
}
```

I've tried different combinations of making this inline and making other tweeks, such as making the 150px width into a percentage, but that would create all sorts of alignment issues with the text.

Here is a demo with all of the code now: http://jsfiddle.net/HSVdg/1/

Some notes on the above link:

1. I am using Tiny Drop Down 2 (http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinydropdown2/) for drop-down functionality (in the form of JS and CSS, which are noted in comments), though the drop down is not actually working in the jsfiddle. I'm pretty sure all of the JS is irrelevant to my main question.
2. Tiny Drop Down uses a lot of CSS, so it's been quite difficult for me to try and make little tweeks.
3. The buttons are not vertically lined up with the actual bar, but again this is not the main issue since this is not happening on my actual site.
4. The window size in the jsfiddle doesn't actually accomodate the entire length of buttons, so you immediately see the problem of the buttons moving to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Try my version, with display table/table-cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/HSVdg/10/

I've basically just replaced floats with `display: table` on **.menu2** and `display: table-cell` on its children (li's)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i see it

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="youarehere"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <li><a>Products</a>
    <li><a>Services</a>
    <li><a>Contact Us</a>
  </ul>
</nav>

ul#navigation {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #039;
}

ul#navigation li { display: inline; }

ul#navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .25em 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #39f;
  border-top: solid 1px #39f;
  border-right: solid 1px #39f;
}
a:link, a:visited { color: #fff; }
ul#navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

ul#navigation li#youarehere a { background-color: #09f; }
```